# Numpy Piecewise ValueError with "AND" conditional operator

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-optimize, piecewise

I'm attempting to fit a three-segment line to a set of data, using `np.piecewise` and `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()`. I can accomplish this for a two-line segment by using the following function:

```
def piecewise_line(t,m1,m2,t0,y0): 
     conds = [t < t0, t >= t0]
     functions =  [lambda t:m1*(t-t0) + y0, lambda t:m2*(t-t0) + y0]
     y = np.piecewise(t,conds,functions)
     return y
```

Then applying it to a set of data, which works without issue.

```
t_space = np.linspace(2,4,100)
y = np.exp(t_space)
p, e = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(piecewise_line, t_space, y)
```

However, when I use a function corresponding to a 3-part piecewise line, as below:

```
def piecewise_line(t,m1,m2,m3,t0,y0,t1): 
     y1 = y0 + m2*(t1-t0)
     conds = [t < t0, (t >= t0) and (t < t1), t >= t1]
     functions = [lambda t:m1*(t-t0) + y0, lambda t:m2*(t-t0) + y0, lambda t:m3*(t-t1) + y1]
     return np.piecewise(t, conds,functions)
```

I get the following error:

```
File ...\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py:26, in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
...
---> 16      conds = [t < t0, (t >= t0) and (t < t1), t >= t1]
     17      functions = [lambda t:m1*(t-t0) + y0, lambda t:m2*(t-t0) + y0, lambda t:m3*(t-t1) + y1]
     18      return np.piecewise(t, conds,functions)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This error isn't thrown if I remove the middle condition, `(t >= t0) and (t < t1)` or change it to a random, singular check (like `t=9999`), but also throws on `t0 <= t < t1`.

What about the middle condition causes this error while the "singular" comparisons don't?

Comment: Use `&` (logical_and) instead of `and`.  `and` is not an operator; it `short-circuits` and doesn't work with arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you! I see why `and` wouldn't work now - but why wouldn't `t0 <= t < t1`?

Comment: `a<b<c` only works for scalars.  Internally I believe it also uses `and`, so does not work with arrays.  It produces the same `ambiguity` error.